# Is there any way to get spl decimal in program?

Tags: anchor, spl-token

Is there any way to get spl decimal in program? Sorry about this, this question is too short so I have to add this sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are writing a program using Anchor, then you can do the following:

Use `anchor_spl` to get the `Mint` type

```
use anchor_spl::token::Mint;
```

Then you can do this in the Accounts struct for your instruction, which deserialized the mint account data for you:

```
#[account(mut)]
pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
```

Within your instruction you should then be able to access the decimals for the mint like this:

```
*ctx.accounts.mint.decimals
```